# Read in effective RAM usage on Linux

Tags: memory, linux, containers

I'm running some programs on *nix inside of a container and I'm attempting to closely calculate the amount of RAM my process is using. It is my understanding that this information should be under `/proc/#{pid}/smaps`. I've tried sum-ing all the PSS of all `smaps` files on a system using this Ruby script: https://gist.github.com/schneems/10025798

However I am seeing Memory usage being reported as lower than what my container is reporting. If I switch over to using RSS, then the value becomes much higher (way over what my container reports). I'm fairly certain that all the information I need is available in `/proc`, I just don't know how it's being reported to get an accurate measurement. My question is this: what values in `smaps` should I be summing as PSS alone is not a good indicator? Is there a better or more accurate way to get this information from within a linux machine?

Answer (score 1):

RSS is the resident set size, in other words the global memory used by a process, included every library loaded at runtime. A single library may be used several times (think of apache processes forks for instance, each sub-process may use the same libraries). According to the Virtual Memory model, each process sees this memory as being used by itself. In reality, the kernel maps the virtual memory addresses to the unique memory address of the library.

On the other hand, PSS sums each USS (Unshared set size) for a process. Think of it as the memory a process would immediately free if we kill it. It does not take into account the shared memory, but only the memory the process is unique to use.

As consequence, the RSS value over-estimate the effective memory used. The PSS is more accurate, if you make sure to take in account the loaded libraries memory size.

More details [here](http://www.openlogic.com/wazi/bid/315941/How-to-measure-memory-usage-in-Linux), specially at the last paragraph.